How to populate a cell with text which is made up using characters from data in other cells?
I have a table in Excel which has a header row and data in cells A2 (text), B2 (text), C2 (text), D2 (text) and E2 (number).  A2, B2, C2, D2 are drop downs with different selectable data.  E2 is a formula to automatically generate an incremental number each time a new row is added to the table.
I would like to auto generate a reference in cell N2 which is made up from the data in A2, B2, C2, D2, E2.  For example:
A2=Apple
B2=Green
C2=Ripe
D2=Location
E2=0001
Desired result in cell N2 would be APP-GRE-RIP-LOC-0001
I've had some success with:
=IF(A2="Apple","APP-"&E2)
The result in cell N2 will be APP-0001.  However I'm unsure how to nest these so the result is different based on the data in the cells.  And also whether there is a more flexible formula as the data in the drop down lists may be expanded over time.
Thanks in advance!

Why not just use =CONCAT(A2&"-"&B2&"-"&C2&"-"&D2&"-"&E2)?  And if D2 is a static string value, I would represent it as a prefix via formatting instead.

Hi, thanks.  This does work partially.  What this produces is Apple-Green-Ripe-Location-0001.  I'm looking for APP-GRE-RIP-LOC-0001

Is the code for each always the first three characters? What is you have Apples and Apple pies? Green and Greenish?

Don't use Concatenate(). It's not required and too much to type. You can simply use the & character.
You seem to want to take the first three characters of the cells and string them together, separated by a dash "-", followed by the value in E2. For that you can use:
=UPPER(LEFT(A2,3)&"-"&LEFT(B2,3)&"-"&LEFT(C2,3)&"-"&LEFT(D2,3)&"-"&E2)

The formula uses the LEFT() function to extract the first three characters from cells A2 to D2, puts a dash between them, concatenates E2 and puts the whole thing into upper case with UPPER()

Or, shorter with
=UPPER(CONCAT(LEFT(A3:D3,3)&"-",E3))



Another option is TEXTJOIN:
=TEXTJOIN("-",,UPPER(LEFT(B2:F2,3)))


Edit:
To correctly return all of the numeric cell, just remove it from the call to LEFT:
=TEXTJOIN("-",,UPPER(LEFT(B2:E2,3)),F2)



Also with TEXTJOIN(), you have the option to include empty cells, or exclude...So if "Green" in the above gets removed, you can choose to return APP-RIP-WAR-000 or APP--RIP-WAR-000
